# How to merge one titanium project with native project in one workspace?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, titanium

I have an ios project with a tabbar, in a tab I have to show the contents of a second simply app developed in Appcelerate Titanium (this app works fine standalone).

I've created a Workspace and added my project and a nested project of titanium app. When i  add a target dependency at my project the build doesn't compile cause is 'Unable to instantiate the UIApplication delegate instance. No class named TiApp is loaded.'

How to correctly include two working project in a workspace and use the views of an target in another?

Please help me in how to merge this two app.

Comment: I believe when you compile the Titanium app it creates an xcode project.  You might be able just use that base project and then search for merging two xcode projects.  You may find more information on that if you aren't looking for it with Titanium.'

Comment: thanks @Martin, i merge two projects correctly, every files is in bundle but if try to alloc a class of an imported file from another project i got: "symbol(s) not found for architecture .." and the .m file is in compile sources